# Mercurial uncommited changes merged when changing branches

Tags: mercurial

I've accidently switched branches while having uncommitted changes. It seems that mercurial has automatically merged my changes, but there are conflicts left behind.

How can I go back to having my named branch checked out and commit my changes there?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that mercurial has automatically merged my changes

In seems only for you (and your Mercurial), because for this toy-repo

```
@  2[tip]   e173e81c9fff   2016-07-08 10:09 +0500   lazybadger
|    Creating branch
|
o  1   befd1e011923   2016-07-08 10:06 +0500   lazybadger
|    Edit
|
o  0   45f15df3f7c9   2016-07-08 10:05 +0500   lazybadger
     Start
```

and dirty working dir at rev. 1

```
>hg id -nib
befd1e011923+ 1+ default
>hg st
M 1.txt
```

update to `tip` **doesn't change** content of file *in working directory*

```
>hg up Feature
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

(note "0 files updated, 0 files merged") and working directory is still dirty

```
>hg id -nib
e173e81c9fff+ 2+ Feature

>hg st
M 1.txt
```

PS - you can just disable update to another changeset if your working directory isn't clean: use `-c` option as mandatory for all `hg up` (create alias)